# First select option always returns login error even though password is correct in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having a rather weird problem with ASP.NET C#.

It seems that I can log in with any other option in my select drop down apart from the first one. I've checked the password in the database and its correct.

Anyone know why this is the case?

Here is my code:

Login.aspx

```
<form id="loginForm" runat="server">
        <asp:Login runat="server" OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate" Width="293px" Height="172px"
            ID="Login_Box">
            <LayoutTemplate>

                <!-- department -->
                <div id="dept" style="text-align: left">
                    Department<br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="UserName" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="dept"
                        DataValueField="id" DataMember="DefaultView">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:team13ConnectionString %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [dept] FROM [ts_dept] ORDER BY [dept]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </div>

                <!-- password -->
                <div id="pass" style="text-align: left">
                    Password:<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                        ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Login1"
                        ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic">Password is required.</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>

                <!-- failure text -->
                <div style="text-align: left; color: Red">
                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Mode="Encode"></asp:Literal>
                </div>
                <br />

                <!-- sign in button -->
                <div class="btn" style="float: right" runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="Login1"
                        CssClass="cupid-green"/>
                </div>

            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:Login>
        </form>
```

Login.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        string username = Login_Box.UserName;
        string pwd = Login_Box.Password;

        string strConn;
        strConn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["team13ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        Conn.Open();

        string sqlUserName;
        sqlUserName = "SELECT id,pass FROM ts_dept ";
        sqlUserName += " WHERE (id ='" + username + "')";
        sqlUserName += " AND (pass ='" + pwd + "')";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlUserName, Conn);

        string CurrentName;
        CurrentName = (string)com.ExecuteScalar();

        if (CurrentName != null)
        {
            Session["UserAuthentication"] = username;
            Session.Timeout = 1;
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Session["UserAuthentication"] = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good I think we would need to see the database to make sure that the users in fact have the correct department id.